# How do I set the intent of menu items defined in an Android menu xml file?

Tags: android, android-widget

How do I set the intent of menu items defined in an Android menu xml file?  For example I currently have...

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:name="Main Menu">
    <item android:title="@string/resume_game" android:icon="@drawable/resume"></item>
    <item android:title="@string/play_golf" android:icon="@drawable/play_golf"></item>
    <item android:title="@string/my_rounds" android:icon="@drawable/my_rounds"></item>
</menu>
```

And in my Activity I have the following method overriden...

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        final MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.about_item);

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give each of your menu items an id, such as android:id="@+id/resume_game", and then you can define the onOptionItemsSelected() method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.resume_game:
            resumeGame();
            return true;
        case R.id.play_golf:
            playGolf();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

What synic says is true, and that approach does allow you to respond to a menu item being selected, I don't believe that answers the question, which is how to set the intent of a menu item defined in an XML file.

That being said, the question confuses me, because it should be obvious that you simply call menuItem.setIntent() on the indicated menu item:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    final MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.about_item);
    menuItem.setIntent(myIntent);
    return true;
}
```

If Benju doesn't know how to create intents and thinks that intents are the only way to respond to menu items, then synic's answer is spot-on.